# How to bridge vboxnet with Wi-Fi on OS X 10.10 "Yosemite"

Tags: macos, network, wifi

I am trying to bridge two interfaces on OS X 10.10 "Yosemite" but somehow this does not seem to work for virtual interfaces:

[image]

The network on Virtualbox goes over "Host Only Network"

[image]

Is there a way to overcome this? I want to bridge 192.168.56.1 with the Wi-Fi in order to make my virtual machines visible to other computers on the internet.

Answer (score 10):

VirtualBox and OS X provide several (no-NAT) methods to connect your VM:

**1. The VirtualBox "Bridged Adapter":**

First remove bridge1 in Terminal and use a "Bridged Adapter" instead of vboxnet0 in your VM. Go to the Network settings of the respective VM -> Adapter1 -> attached to: and change the type from whatever it is now to "Bridged Adapter" then choose your Wi-Fi interface:

[image: network settings vm virtualbox]

The VM's en0 attached to the bridged adapter has to be configured with a unique IP in the same network range as the hosts interface IP.

Example:

- My hosts en1 config: network: 192.168.1.0/24 IP: 192.168.1.2 gateway: 192.168.1.1
- The VM's eth0 config: network: 192.168.1.0/24 IP: a free and unique IP-address in the range 192.168.1.3-192.168.1.254 gateway: 192.168.1.1

If you want to make the VM accessible to other computers in the WAN (internet) (e.g. a web-server) you have to forward the respective ports in the router to the VM's IP. The VM can be accessed by all other computers in the same network (192.168.1.0/24) in your LAN directly.

Finally it looks like this:

```
WAN <---> Router/Switch (& port fw to VM) <----> Mac <-------> VM
           192.168.1.1                      192.168.1.2   192.168.1.130
                ¦
                ¦
             other Mac(s)
           192.168.1.3|4|5...
```

**2. The OS X bridge**

I assume en1 is your Wi-Fi interface and eth0 is the first adapter in your (Linux-)VM. Check this with `ifconfig` on your VM-host. Please adapt the commands and change the interfaces below if necessary.

If you don't want to use "Bridged Adapter" but vboxnet0 do the following after starting VirtualBox:

Attach the VM adapter 1 to the "Host-only Adapter" and the "Name" vboxnet0.

On the host in Terminal enter:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
sudo ifconfig bridge1 destroy #if bridge1 still exists
sudo ifconfig en1 down
sudo ifconfig vboxnet0 down
sudo ifconfig bridge1 create
sudo ifconfig bridge1 addm vboxnet0 addm en1
sudo ifconfig bridge1 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

In the VM (Linux) you have to configure an IP-address and a default route:

```
sudo ipconfig eth0 192.168.56.101 netmask 255.255.255.0 arp
sudo route add default gw 192.168.56.1
```

A configured "Network Manager" might interfere with those settings.

On the various Macs in your network you have to configure an additional static route:

```
sudo route -n add -net 192.168.56.0/24 192.168.1.2
```

On the router your have to forward ports to the VM and add a static route to 192.168.56.0/24 to make the VM accessible to other computers in the WAN (internet).

Finally it looks like this:

```
WAN <---> Router/Switch (& port fw to VM & static route to 192.168.56.0/24) <-----> Mac <----------------------> VM
           192.168.1.1                                                    192.168.1.2|192.168.56.1   192.168.56.101 (& default gw or static route to 192.168.1.0/24)
                ¦
                ¦
             other Mac(s)
           192.168.1.3|4|5... (& static route to 192.168.56.0/24)
```

The bridge and the various routes (except those on the router and the default gateway of the VM) don't survive a reboot.

To roll-back all changes:

To remove bridge1 on the host do the following:

```
sudo ifconfig bridge1 down
sudo ifconfig bridge1 deletem en1 deletem vboxnet0
sudo ifconfig bridge1 destroy
```

To disable forwarding on the host do the following:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=0
```

To remove static routes on the Mac enter:

```
sudo route -n delete -net 192.168.56.0/24 192.168.1.2
```

Remove the static route on the Router.

---

As a result one might say it's much easier and much more comfortable to use method 1.

Comment: I am not sure if this is true for vboxnet0 (host only network).

Comment: yes, since lauch. Works perfectly. This is another interface by the way. Goto: preferences -> network.

Comment: I have created the bridge1 as you described and it shows up in ifconfig bridge1 correcly. However, I can not reach the VM from another computer by 192.168.56.150. The shared subnet is 192.168.0.1. I have also tried it with the changed attached adapter like you showed, but then the VM has no access to anywhere. Alll pings fail.

Comment: @merlin I completely reworked my answer to get everything working

Comment: My CentOS also needed dhcp enabled.